# ListView Not showing anything about observable collection data binding

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding, observablecollection

In the view, I have a ListView that should be shown a with a data binding with an Observable collection of string, but not shown anything

If instead of listview I put a label and the observable collection turns it into a simple string I see the data

**In the Main view:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialsPorts}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding SerialPortName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**In the Main ViewModel**

```
 class BrightnessSerialsPortsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IBrightnessSerialsPortsViewModel
    {

        //readonly IPageDialogService pageDialogService;
        readonly IBrightnessSerialsPortsManager manager;

        public BrightnessSerialsPortsViewModel()
        {
            //pageDialogService = new PageDialogService();

            manager = new BrightnessSerialsPortsManager();

            manager.BrightnessInfoUpdated += OnBrightnessInfoUpdated;
            manager.DeviceSerialPortsInfoUpdated += OnDeviceSerialsPortsInfoUpdated;

            PageAppearingCommand = new Command(OnPageAppearing);
            PageDisappearingCommand = new Command(OnPageDisappearing);
        }

        void OnPageAppearing()
        {
            //pageDialogService.DisplayAlert("Invoke Command Demo Page", "Appearing event fired.", "OK");
            manager.GetBrightness();
            manager.GetSerialsPorts();
        }

        void OnPageDisappearing()
        {
            //pageDialogService.DisplayAlert("Invoke Command Demo Page", "Disappearing event fired.", "OK");
            SerialTest = "";
        }


        private void OnDeviceSerialsPortsInfoUpdated(object sender, IDeviceSerialsPortsInfoEventArgs e)
        {
          foreach(string device in e.DeviceSerialsPorts.Devices)
            {
                ISerialsPortsViewModel serialsPortsViewModel = new SerialsPortsViewModel(device);
                SerialsPorts.Add(serialsPortsViewModel);

                SerialTest += device + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        private void OnBrightnessInfoUpdated(object sender, IBrightnessInfoEventArgs e)
        {
            float f = e.DeviceBrightness.Brightness;
            decimal dec = new decimal(f);
            Brightness = (double) dec;
        }

        //public ICommand ChangeBrightnessCommand { get; set; }

        public ICommand PageAppearingCommand { get; private set; }

        public ICommand PageDisappearingCommand { get; private set; }

        public ICommand ChangeBrightnessCommand => new RelayCommand(() => ExcecuteChangeBrightnessCommand());

        public void ExcecuteChangeBrightnessCommand()
        {

        }

        private ObservableCollection<ISerialsPortsViewModel> serialsPorts = new ObservableCollection<ISerialsPortsViewModel>();

        public ObservableCollection<ISerialsPortsViewModel> SerialsPorts { get=> serialsPorts ; set { serialsPorts = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialsPorts)); } }

        private string serialstest = "";

        public string SerialTest { get => serialstest; set {serialstest = value ; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialTest)); } }

        private double brightness = 1.0;

        public double Brightness { get => brightness; set {brightness = value ; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Brightness)); } }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**In the SerialPorts ViewModel:**

```
 public SerialsPortsViewModel(string serialPortName)
        {
            SerialPortName = serialPortName;
        }

        private string serialPortName;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string SerialPortName { get=> serialPortName; set {serialPortName = value ; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialPortName)); } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the `BindingContext` ?

Comment: yes, if I replace the ListView with a simple label and I replace the observable collection with a simple string, the data appear

Comment: Why do I think you are binding a collection of interfaces to the View?

Comment: using the breakpoint I see that the observable collection has value, only that in the Views nothing is seen

Comment: Check the name of model is `SerialsPortsViewModel` or `ISerialsPortsViewModel` .

Comment: I don't have the model here, just the view and the ViewModel.

Comment: Is the part of xaml right or did I miss something?

Comment: You can share a sample which contains the issue.Don't forget to remove your personal info ,such as password and account ID .

Comment: I've already posted the code

Comment: I need the sample so that I can test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Solved change the View to this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialsPorts}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Height="60">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="10" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,5,10,5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding SerialPortName}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```